# Notification badges are not appearing on Android 10 and 11

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have tried using showBadge method and have also enabled show home screen app icon badge from settings in device on Android 10 but badges doesn't got displayed. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: does your launcher app supports badges? (does any other app shows badges?)

Comment: yes twitter is showing in Android 10

Comment: Default system launcher is not showing any settings to turn on notification badge. But when i installed microsoft launcher badge got displayed. What is the default way to do so? A third user won't install launcher

Comment: @Aditi Did you find out the solution? I am facing the same issue, my app even doesn't show the home screen app icon toggle button in notification settings.